# System of two equations with two different non-linear variables

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have to solve this system of equations for real $x$ and $y$:

$2x^3+4=x^2(y+3)$

$2y^3+4=y^2(x+3)$

I noticed that they are symetric and, assuming that $x=y$, I got two solutions: $x=y=-1$ or $x=y=2$, which are correct (I checked with the answers), however, I do not know how to show that they are the only solutions. Please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x,y)=(2,2),(-1,-1)$ are the only real solutions.

In the following, suppose that $x\not=y$.

Let $x+y=\alpha,xy=\beta$. Then we have
$$\begin{align}&(2x^3+4)+(2y^3+4)=x^2(y+3)+y^2(x+3)\\&\iff 2(x^3+y^3)+8=xy(x+y)+3(x^2+y^2)\\&\iff 2(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)+8=xy(x+y)+3((x+y)^2-2xy)\\&\iff 2\alpha(\alpha^2-3\beta)+8=\alpha\beta +3(\alpha^2-2\beta)\tag1\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}&(2x^3+4)-(2y^3+4)=x^2(y+3)-y^2(x+3)\\&\iff 2(x^3-y^2)=xy(x-y)+3(x-y)(x+y)\\&\iff 2(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(x-y)(xy+3(x+y))\\&\iff (x-y)(2\alpha^2-2\beta-\beta-3\alpha)=0\\&\Rightarrow \beta=\frac{2\alpha^2-3\alpha}{3}\tag2\end{align}$$

So, from $(1)(2)$, 
$$2\alpha(\alpha^2-(2\alpha^2-3\alpha))+8=\alpha\cdot\frac{2\alpha^2-3\alpha}{3} +3\left(\alpha^2-2\cdot\frac{2\alpha^2-3\alpha}{3}\right)$$
$$\iff 4\alpha^3-12\alpha^2+9\alpha -12=0\tag3$$

By the way, since $x,y$ are the roots of $t^2-\alpha t+\beta=0$, if $\alpha^2-4\beta\lt 0$, i.e. if $$\alpha\lt 0\quad\text{or}\quad \alpha\gt 2.4$$
then there is no such $(x,y)\in\mathbb R$.

Now you can easily see that $(3)$ has *only one* real root $\alpha$ such that $2.5\lt\alpha\lt 3$.

Hence, there are no other real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering now what if there would be system of n simultaneous equations, I mean
$2x_1^3+4=x_1^2(x_2+3)$

$2x_2^3+4=x_2^2(x_3+3)$

...

$2x_n^3+4=x_n^2(x_1+3)$?